# Nginx configuration in OpenShift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, docker-compose, openshift

I have been struggling with a solution to have nginx running, in OpenShift there is no use of root user during creation of the containers. Then, I was getting the following error:

```
2023/06/21 10:37:45 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

This is happening because the user is not root. The Dockerfile used for the configuration is the following:

```
# base image
FROM node:14.21.2 as build-deps

#more lines

RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80

RUN printenv
RUN ln -s /tmp/env.js /usr/share/nginx/html/static/env.js
CMD ["sh", "-c", "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/static/env.template.js > /tmp/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Then, I changed the nginx image to use **nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.23.2** to avoid the issue when creating the directory `/var/cache/nginx/client_temp`. I modified the Dockerfile shown above to remove the symbolic link and modified the last line to refer to the original path:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/static/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/static/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

However, because this image (Debian OS) is using nginx as user, I am having issues to create the file env.js:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /usr/share/nginx/html/static/env.js: Permission denied
```

If I want to proceed with the creation of symbolic link as the first dockerfile example, then I get the following error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/nginx/html/static/env.js': Permission denied
```

This image is using nginx belonging to the group nginx:

```
$ howami
/bin/sh: 1: howami: not found
$ id nginx
uid=101(nginx) gid=101(nginx) groups=101(nginx)
```

attempting to create a symbolic link to env.js file in static folder is failing because nginx is not part of the root group:

```
$ cd /usr/share/nginx/html/
$ ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 20 22:58 static
```

I cannot change permissions of the directory because this is happening before having the container up.

How could I have the environment variables under /usr/share/nginx/html/static folder in the same way I was trying to do with envsubst and have env.js with the values?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It might not an answer you want, however I think the blog*1 could be helpful for you.

OpenShift has a template for Nginx to deploy on. So you can deploy Nginx using the template.
Here is the parameters which the template have

```
$ oc process openshift//nginx-example --parameters
NAME                     DESCRIPTION                                                                                               GENERATOR           VALUE
NAME                     The name assigned to all of the frontend objects defined in this template.                                                    nginx-example
NAMESPACE                The OpenShift Namespace where the ImageStream resides.                                                                        openshift
NGINX_VERSION            Version of NGINX image to be used (1.20-el8 by default).                                                                      1.20-el8
MEMORY_LIMIT             Maximum amount of memory the container can use.                                                                               512Mi
SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL    The URL of the repository with your application source code.                                                                  https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-ex.git
SOURCE_REPOSITORY_REF    Set this to a branch name, tag or other ref of your repository if you are not using the default branch.                       
CONTEXT_DIR              Set this to the relative path to your project if it is not in the root of your repository.                                    
APPLICATION_DOMAIN       The exposed hostname that will route to the nginx service, if left blank a value will be defaulted.                           
GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET    Github trigger secret.  A difficult to guess string encoded as part of the webhook URL.  Not encrypted.   expression          [a-zA-Z0-9]{40}
GENERIC_WEBHOOK_SECRET   A secret string used to configure the Generic webhook.                                                    expression          [a-zA-Z0-9]{40}
```

When I tried deploying an Nginx with the template, I needed to modify the image tag from nginx:1.20-el8 to nginx:1.20-ubi8. Other than that, there is nothing else to be done.

*1: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/openshift-aws-nginx-web-server